# WPF (MVVM): where to put existing "assembly" / "application logic" - in a model or viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have some kind of experience with WinForms coding but I am trying to do my new stuff with WPF (and the mvvm pattern).
One thing I am going round in circles for days searching the internet is to get the following right:

What do I have to implement in a model and what in the viewmodel when it goes down to "manage the repository (model?) data".

(I think) I do understand the basic concept of mvvm and decopeling all the data but I struggle to figure out the right implementation.

Let's assume I have an existing service (application without any UI) which is able to read values from a (ini) configuration file, do some stuff what its intended for, and write configurations to the local registry. Perhaps in future I want  change the configuration to be stored in xml or json instead of ini. From my point of view this is all well placed in the existing code - let's say a configuration.cs file with a class configurations - which currently has absolutely nothing to do with my new wpf console application I want to implement next.

```
namespace ExistingConfigurationCode
{
    public enum Setting
    {   
        some,
        values
    }
    public class ConfigurationItemProperties
    {
        public property1
        public property 2
    }

    public class ApplicationConfiguration
    {
        List<ConfigurationItemProperties> config;

        public void LoadConfig()
        public void SaveConfig()
    }
}
```

As just said, now I do want to implement a UI to enable a user to set up those configurations.

For what I have understand until now is:

- the view is only the view and contains no logic at all
- the viewmodel is responsible to "deliver" all needed informations to the view and receive commands from the view
- the model is a model of the data we are dealing with

My problem in understanding (and knowledge how to proceed) is:

- is this existing class already my model? But it does not make sense to add all the RaisePropertyChange stuff in this class because it is also used in the service. Also I have seen a lot of tutorials where I am told to not put any code in the model
- if the existing class should be in my view model, what do I need the model for than?
- Should the model have only a reference to my already existing class and control all read and write stuff to the registry/xml/ini through some kind of a wrapper?
- Where do I have to add the "RaisePropertyChange" getter and setter? Because they are "controlling" the UI I would guess they should be placed in the view model, but I have seen a lot of examples where they are also in the model?

I got some kind of stuck here.
I thought the binding should be between the view and the view model, so the RaisePropertyChange should be in the view model, but in this case I would have to recreate everything a second time in the view model

**Additional informations in response to comments**

I understood now, that I can use my existing code as the model.

Besides the already existing "execution engine" which is utilizing the existing namespace/class, I have to create two applications with UI. An "admin console" and an end user console. 
(I think) I am fine with the admin console, because it has a view for all the properties of ConfigurationItemProperties, so I can following Fabios first explanations. 
But the second UI for the end user should have a stripped down UI, probably a listview with some checkboxes per list view item. And here is my problem.
 
For the listview I need the ObservableCollection, but for the items in the list view I need the "facade" fabio mentioned. Am I right so far?

If so, the ObservableCollection AND "ConfigurationItemPropertiesFacade" are working with the "model" which does not have any implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged or INotifyCollectionChanges stuff. But I think the "collections" must refer to the "single items" from the facade because the collection (from the view model) has no reference to the facade in the view model.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from using `ObservableCollection` in `ApplicationConfiguration`. However, I would recommend that you place all your configuration into your project configuration class. That already implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's think about these definitions:

1. **Model** - Data access and business Logic.
2. **ViewModel** - it's responsibility is to provide model's data and logic to view in such way that is easily consumable from view.

I believe that these definition gives you clear answer:

### `ExistingConfigurationCode` class should be considered as part of your model.

Few more thoughts however:

- INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollection changed is not limited to DataBinding or WPF. These interfaces are much more general.
- There nothing wrong about implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in a Model if you want your model to notify other layers or compoments about changes
- It's common practice that you bind your Views directly to Model entities. ViewModel often just expose entity from Model as a property.
- Wrapping model properties in ViewModel is one way of doing it. Another way is having separate properties in ViewModel with their own backing fields. You set the ViewModel properties to initial values when user visits the page and you save the edited values back to Model when user clicks save.

Comment: thanks, I understood so far. Please check updated question above

Comment: You are asking whether you should create facade/wrapper just to hide some properties from model? Well, I think is is not worth it unless you are using something like AutoGenerateColumns, or you need some extra logic in the facade. INotifyPropertyChanged implementation may be such extra logic

Comment: no, the point is, my existing code is used in an existing "engine" which is only consuming the configuration. absolutely no changes are made at this point (everything is "readonly"). Therefor (and because I did not code before with wpf/mvvm) there is no "notification" stuff in it. I think I really have to add the INPC implementation because of wpf (which I need only on a few PCs whereas the "engine" is used on all PCs (and I would not like - if not necessary) to change the existing code - what by the way is what I like at the "models" decoupling from the view model

Comment: Wouldn it be easier to replace underlying model completely, once you click save in the view?

Answer (score 2):

Try to think about `MVVM` like about three layers(not files) of your application.

- View - namespace/project which contains only view logic(XAML and code
  behind)
- Model - namespace/project which contains all "business logic"
- ViewModel - namespace/project which contains logic to link View and
  Model without knowing about View's namespace. Another words ViewModel layer's responsibility to be a bridge between Model and View - Call Model's method, raise `PropertyChanged` event for when some value changed to inform View about changes.

So keep all your logic of configuration in the Model namespace.
In case when Model class need to be represent in the View with editing possibilities, create Facade class in the ViewModel layer

```
public class ConfigurationItemPropertiesFacade : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ConfigurationItemProperties _Model;

    public string Property1
    {
        get { return _Model.Property1; }
        set
        {
            if(Equals(_Model.Property1, value)) return;
            _Model.Property1 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ConfigurationItemPropertiesFacade(ConfigurationItemProperties model)
    {
        _Model = model;
    }
}
```

Use `ConfigurationItemPropertiesFacade` class as ViewModel in the View.
With this approach your Model layer stays clean and can be used anywhere.

**In response on comment:**
*So tutorials telling it is not allowed to put "code" in the model are wrong, right?*
Again try thinking about `Model` in `MVVM` not like a one class/file, but layer/namespace/project which can contains more then one class.
There is no right or wrong - you can implement your logic as you fill better suite your specifications. But if you will respect **Single responsibility principle**  (https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/17170/102569), then you will separate responsibilities of `ApplicationConfiguration` to (I didn't know inner logic of methods `Load` and `Save`)

- "Model" class which represents only data, class which has no
  functionality just properties for keeping data. 
  You have this already `ConfigurationItemProperties`
- "Service" classes which contains functionality of saving and loading
  configurations. Your class can be spitted in two classes.

```cs
// Have one responsibility take configurations as parameter and save them somewhere
public class SaveService  
{
    public void Save(List<ConfigurationItemProperties> items) {}
}

// Have one responsibility load configurations and return them to the caller
public class LoadService
{
    public List<ConfigurationItemProperties> Load() {}
}
```

So then your ViewModel will use those classes to represent and modify configurations in UI.

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly LoadService _LoadService;
    private readonly SaveService _SaveService;

    //Here you can use your"Facade" implementation
    private ObservableCollection<ConfigurationItemPropertiesFacade> _Items
    public ObservableCollection<ConfigurationItemPropertiesFacade> Items 
    { 
        get { return _Items; } 
        set
        {
            _Items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameOf(Items));
        } 
    }

    public ICommand Save { get; set; }
    public ICommand Load { get; set; }

    public ViewModel(LoadService loadService, SaveService saveService)
    {
        _LoadService = loadService;
        _SaveService = saveService;

        // Create command instance for Save
        // Create command instance for Load

        var itemsList = _LoadService.Load();
        var facadeItems = itemsList.Select(item => new ConfigurationItemPropertiesFacade(item));
        Items = new ObservableCollection(facadeItems);
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks, this makes sense to me. So tutorials telling it is not allowed to put "code" in the model are wrong, right? But I am still struggling. The existing class "application configuration" has all the stuff regarding reading and writing complete configurations implemented. It has the List of the ConfigurationItemProperties implemented. If I'm write, this List should be a ObservableCollection. Is the implementation of the view model just the same as you have shown for the configurationItempProperties? Just using the ObservableCollection as the type of the getter/setter?

Comment: @alexknopp, check updated answer

Comment: @alexknopp I feel you are confused about the `MVVM` term `Model` meaning "application logic" and the `DDD` term `Model` meaning "a thing, whose state my code manipulate". These are overlapping but distinct concepts. The `MVVM` `Model` encompasses the entirety of the `DDD` hierarchy.

Comment: @Fabio: I think I am following already the Single Resonsibility Principle having a class "ConfigurationItemProperties" and a separate class "ApplicationConfiguration" having the methods for loading and saving. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @Fabio: Besides this, I think now we are exactly at my struggling point. I need the ObservableCollection to show the list in a list view, but when changing something (checked list view) I am changing a value of a single ConfigurationItem (and therefor the complete list too, I know). But the getter/setter from ConfigurationItemPropertiesFacade are referencing ConfigurationItem - Properties, and the ObservableCollection is referencing ConfigurationItemProperties. Do the ObservableCollection not need to reference ConfigurationItemPropertiesFacade? I hope my "problem" is understandable.

Comment: My sample was only example of "Model" which contains more then one class. I am not argued about your implementation - there are always some other method to do :)

Comment: I was to lazy change `ConfigurationItem` to facade implementation. So you are right in ViewModel must be used facade class. Then you get properties modified without implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on Model class

Comment: @Aron. I understand the part *term Model meaning "application logic"* but I am not sure about *term Model meaning "a thing, whose state my code manipulate"*.  Is the second part not something which is located in the view model?

Comment: I this case I would not create facade/wrapper for ConfigurationItem. I would create `PageViewModel` and ObservableCollection of `ConfigurationItemViewModel`. So far completely indipendent from Model. ConfigurationItemViewModel would be as simple as possible and would exactly match purposes of UI. Nothing more nothing less. This allows creating UI even without model (UX first approach) and it improves readability. When the UI is nice and done, just load the ObservableCollection from from Model in `PageViewModel.Load` and save data back to Model in `PageViewModel.Save`.

Comment: @Liero, This seems same as Facade approach with different names, where `ConfigurationItemViewModel` = `ConfigurationItemPropertiesFacade`, maybe with different inner implemetation, but from outside both have same behavior. Your approach will work until `ConfigurationItemProperties` have some additional logic in case where some property have updated. Then independent `ConfigurationItemViewModel` will need to know about Model

Comment: Lets not talk about names ;) Especially in such case (logic in model when changing its state) I preffer my approach. Just my experience from many many projects. Its easier to meet different UX requirements then, imo.